# SourceTree doesn't show the differences in Unity scene files?

Tags: unity, assets, version-control, git

Back in the day it worked, but for some reason in my new projects it isn't.

Every other asset's difference is shown correctly in a text format (i.e. `.prefab`), only `.unity` files won't work, in the diff view it says:

> No changes in this file have been detected, or it is a binary file.

**I did these:**

- In `Project Settings > Editor`, `Asset Serialization` is set to `Force Text`.
- Created a `.gitconfig` in the root of my repo, with this content: (the path is correct)

  `[merge]
  tool = unityyamlmerge
  [mergetool "unityyamlmerge"]
  trustExitCode = false
  cmd = 'C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Tools\UnityYAMLMerge.exe' merge -p "$BASE" "$REMOTE" "$LOCAL" "$MERGED"`
- Also in `SourceTree > Tools > Options > Diff`, I increased a few limits, set the external diff and merge tool to `C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Tools\UnityYAMLMerge.exe` but none of them helped.

Comment: Potential useful link: https://www.deadlyfingers.net/code/unity-git